# Demo and Production Application in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a web application running on Tomcat 7 where I need to access different databases based on the URL using the same code base. For example:

https://host.com/foo:8080   --> should access the database foo_demo
https://host.com/foo:8089   --> should access the database foo_production

I have tried to deploy 2 separate projects in the webapps directory (one demo and the other production) but I think that is causing problems with session handling on the server.

Comment: What are `8080`, `8089` in your case? I'm tempted to think they are ports but the URL doesn't support my theory.

Comment: good point adarshr, they should ready https://host.com:8080/foo and https://host.com:8089. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify your DB via META-INF/context.xml

the productive-tomcat will create his own configuration. You can permanently change the Database here!

You wont have session-problems because there is no session-replication by default.

NOTE: Ensure the /conf/server.xml's host-Node contains the copyXML-Attribute with value "true".
Default value is set to False

Comment: I think you're on to something. It seems like I would be using the <Resource> element, is that right? If so my question is how can I map a URL or port to use the correct <Resource> configuration (assuming there are 2 or more <Resource> elements)?